# Direct reduction $L_{REG}\le_m L_{CFG}$

Tags: computability, turing-machines, reductions

Both $L_{REG}=\{ \langle M \rangle : L(M)\text{ is regular}\}$ and $L_{CFG}=\{ \langle M \rangle : L(M)\text{ is context-free}\}$ are $\le_m$-complete for $\Sigma_3^0$ in the arithmetic hierarchy. This of course implies that $L_{REG}\le_m L_{CFG}$. Can anyone come up with natural, intuitive, direct reduction?

[I can give a reduction that goes through 
$L_{COF}=\{ \langle M \rangle : L(M)\text{ is cofinite}\}$,
which is also complete for $\Sigma_3^0$. But it's not at all clear how to extract a direct reduction from the indirect one.]

Comment: I'd try to use the Chomsky–Schützenberger representation theorem but I'm not sure how yet.

Comment: I don't see how the Chomsky–Schützenberger representation theorem is applicable here.

Comment: @Aryeh : You take your $L$ and feed it to your CFG-oracle. If it accepts, then you try to "complexify" the language in some way so that if it was regular it becomes context-free but if it wasn't, the result isn't context-free. Something like the ND defined in section 4.3 of http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~berstel/Articles/1997CFLPDA.pdf

Comment: I don't understand what "take your $L$ and  feed it to your CFG-oracle" means.

Comment: @Aryeh Don't mind that. I thought you had to check if the language is context-free first and then complexify it and test the complexified version (which you can do because by making the alphabets disjoint, you can test if two languages are CFLs by testing if their union is). But you may not have to.

Comment: @xavierm02 *how* do you check if a language is context-free?! In an computable fashion?..

Comment: @Aryeh You're doing a reduction. So you assume that you have a magic oracle that does that. And then you are building a computable function to use that magic oracle to solve another problem. All I said is that if you have a magic oracle for $L_{CFG}$, you can build one for $\{<M, N> : L(M) \in CFL \land L(N)\in CFL\}$.

Comment: @xavierm02 I'm doing a mapping reduction, not a Turing reduction. If you have a solution, why not post it as a full answer?

Comment: @Aryeh I understand that. What I'm saying is, there should be some (computable) way $C$ to complexify the language a language $L$ so that $L\in REG \iff C(L)\in CFG$ (or maybe $C(L)\in CFG \land L \in CFG$ which is the same thing as $\alpha C(L)\sqcup \beta L\in CFG$ with $\alpha,\beta$ new letter) | I do not have an answer. I just have ideas.

Comment: I see lots of interesting discussion here in the comments.  Can you edit the question to incorporate the approaches you considered or that have been suggested to you and why you rejected them, and then remove the comments (or flag them as obsolete)?  Ideally, we prefer questions to stand on their own so that readers don't have to read a long comment thread to understand the question or what approaches you've already considered.